# box2d:Disable bounce on collision

Tags: iphone, box2d-iphone

I have some box,creating using box2d,which restitution's are set to zero.but when they fall
over one another there appear bounce event.but i don't want that...i want them not move when fall over another.it can be done if i switch off gravity.but i also want gravity.here is my code

```
UIImage *imageOfSnowV1 = [ UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Object%d.png",currentlySelected]];
    CCTexture2D  *texOfSnowV1 = [[ [CCTexture2D alloc] initWithImage:imageOfSnowV1 ] autorelease];
    CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:texOfSnowV1  rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 32, 32)];
    [self addChild:sprite];
    sprite.position = ccp(p.x, p.y);
    sprite.tag=[temp intValue];


    // Define the dynamic body.
    //Set up a 1m squared box in the physics world

    b2BodyDef bodyDef;
    bodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;

    bodyDef.position.Set(p.x/PTM_RATIO, p.y/PTM_RATIO);
    bodyDef.userData = sprite;
    b2Body *bodyS = world->CreateBody(&bodyDef);

    // Define another box shape for our dynamic body.

    b2PolygonShape dynamicBox;
    dynamicBox.SetAsBox(.5f, .5f);//These are mid points for our 1m box




    b2MassData massData;
    massData.mass = 0.1f;
        bodyS->SetMassData(&massData);


    // Define the dynamic body fixture.
    b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;
    fixtureDef.shape = &dynamicBox; 
    fixtureDef.density = 50.0f;
    fixtureDef.restitution=0.0f;
    fixtureDef.friction = 0.01f;


    bodyS->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);
```

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

As I remember box2d by default uses maximal restitution of colliding objects so even if you have dynamic body restitution set to 0 if the static body have any larger than 0 then that restitution will be used for collision, you could modify b2MixRestitution function to meet your needs.

Cheers,
Krzysztof Zabłocki

Comment: @ Krzysztof Zabłocki:i also tried that..already modify the inline function....but no luck

Comment: maybe in your collision delegate set to sleep the dynamic object? that's a hack but may work.

Comment: i did this     void BeginContact(b2Contact* contact)
 
 { 
  b2Body* bodyA = contact->GetFixtureA()->GetBody();
  b2Body* bodyB = contact->GetFixtureB()->GetBody();
  if ( bodyA->GetType()==b2_dynamicBody && bodyB->GetType()==b2_dynamicBody) {
   
   bodyA->SetAwake(false);
   bodyB->SetAwake(false);
  } 
  }

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same problem lately. My solution, just zero-out the Y coordinate when you detect a new collision in your contact listener. It does the trick perfectly here.

Answer (score 0):

you have to increase velocityIterations and positionIterations. If the bodies are fast they will overlap. so you need better calculation. depends on bodies count you might get perfomance issues, just play with this values.

```
int32 velocityIterations = 10;
int32 positionIterations = 8;
world->Step( timeStep, velocityIterations, positionIterations );
```